# To handle a child window closes on clicking a particular webelement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application I am handling a  window which closes when we click on a particular web-element , with selenium WebDriver with java. 
Here I am able to click on the window and the window is being closed as it is to be, but the next line of code is not being executed and there is no error or exception it is just waiting indefinitely.Could any one find me a solution for the same?

Comment: why don't you switch to original window after this?

Comment: What are your exact steps? What worked for you? Show code. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Gaurang but in this case I am not even able to type a print statement after clicking on that element in the child window, which closes on that click.

Comment: Hana did you tried code I posted

Comment: @shailendra, I have tried the same but it is not working for me.

Comment: for ( String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
         driver.switchTo().window(handle);}
//getObject is a common function to find and return a webelement.
  
   Element=driver.findElement(cfunc.getObject(Objrepopath,Objectpage,objectString));
element.click();
//this is to click on the web element
//here the click action is performed and the childwindow is closed but the further line s of code is not being executed nor any exception thrown.
System.out.println("hai");
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
//it is not even executing a print statement after executing the 'click()'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that after clicking butoon and closing window, due to some unknown reason driver is still waiting to get response from Click() . So I will suggest instead of using Click() method of element . use javascript to click it.

Try below code :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement closeBtn= webDriver.findElement(btn_locator);
```

`JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;`

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", closeBtn);
```

if "executor.executeScript" does not work then try "executor.executeAsyncScript":

```
executor.executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].click();", closeBtn);
```

If you have have made any switch to new window then switch back to main window

Comment: Thanks shailendra, but it is not working for me, here also it is waiting after click().

Comment: Do one more try. After Closing Window, get window handles, switch to window, and then try to interact it.

Comment: There may be 2-3 reasons for the issue you are facing: 1) After performing Click() operation , driver is still waiting to get control. In this case JavaScript code should help you. 2) You have not switched window correctly after click(). 3) Application is getting hang once perform click() operation.

Comment: Also try Mouse Click() using  ActionChain class.

Answer (score -1):

After closing window write below code :
First try this

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

If above code does not work then try below code.

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Comment: Hi @Hana : sorry to hear it. it seems that after clicking due to some unknown reason driver is still waiting to get response from Click() . So I will suggest instead of using Click() method of element . use javascript to click it. Try below code :

WebElement closeBtn= webDriver.findElement(btn_locator);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", closeBtn);

If you have have made any switch to new window then switch back to main window.